# Unix env path variable with wave sign

Tags: unix, path, environment-variables

on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, xenial, I wanted to declare environment variable, which contains a path to my `~/.virtualenvs` folder.

**What I want**:

To have an system-wide environment string variable, which I can use in my unix commands, for example `cd $MYVAR` or in similar elegant usage.

**What I tried:**

I added following line into `/etc/environment` file and then restarted server:

```
$PATH_VENV="~/.virtualenvs"
```

**Problem:**

When I try to use my newly declared variable within unix commands, this is an output:

```
cd ${PATH_VENV}
-bash: cd: ~/.virtualenvs: No such file or directory
```

I think UNIX literally interprets `~/.virtualenvs` as name of folder, instead interpretting `~` as home folder. How to solve this? Is there any workaround?

**Wierd Hint:**

I inspected my `$PATH_VENV` variable like follows, and found out, there is an additional newline, However I have no idea why:

```
echo $PATH_VENV | od -a
0000000   ~   /   .   v   i   r   t   u   a   l   e   n   v   s  nl
0000017
```

Comment: Try `$PATH_VENV=~/.virtualenvs`. Without the quotes

Comment: Recently tried that too. The result is the same as with quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your */etc/environment* file should not contain a dollar-sign before the var name. Second, POSIX 1003 shells like bash perform tilde expansion before parameter expansion. If you type `man bash` read the section named `EXPANSION`. The problem is that */etc/environment* is read (on Linux at least) by the pam_env module which does not perform tilde expansion. If you run `env | grep PATH_VENV` you will see that the tilde has not been replaced with your home directory. And because POSIX 1003 shells perform tilde expansion before variable expansion you end up doing the equivalent of `cd '~/.virtualenvs'` (note the quotes around the path).

The answer is to not set this var in */etc/environment*. Set it in your *~/.profile* or *~/.bashrc*.

P.S., The "additional newline" is because you used `echo` which, by default, appends a newline to the string it echoes.

P.P.S., What you called a "wave" sign is normally called the "tilde" character.